# How to secure a domain from public view?

Tags: .htaccess, security, redirect, drupal

I explain the situation : I have one domain which is not secured and I have a Drupal website. The unsecured domain and the Drupal website are on the same server (same IP).

Is there a way to allow only Drupal website to access the unsecured domain throught a iFrame for instance and set a IP restriction for unsercured domain to let access only from Drupal.

Or you suggest that the use of HTTP_REFERER could be a solution?

Or the only way is secure the unsecured domain ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague/imprecise? What do you mean with "unsecured domain"? What is your scenario here? You can configure your web server in such a way, that only the drupal website is accessible and the other content (whatever that is, i did not understand) is accessible only by drupal.

In Apache for example, you could set two different VirtualHosts, one public, and one that can be accessed only be the IP of your server.

Why you would chose such a set up is not very clear to be honest, maybe you could elaborate on your scenario a bit.